# Cannot save data into database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2012

**object reference not set to the instance of an object** I  am making management system but due to this error I could not saved my data in the databse

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            row[1] = textBox1.Text;
            row[2] = textBox2.Text;
            row[3] = textBox3.Text;
            row[4] = textBox4.Text;
            row[5] = textBox5.Text;
            row[6] = textBox6.Text;

            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);

            clas.UpdateDatabase(ds);
            maxrows = maxrows + 1;
            inc = maxrows - 1;
            MessageBox.Show("DATA INSERTED");

        }

        catch (Exception err)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);

        }
 class Class1
{
    public string sql_string;
    public string strCon;

    public string Sql
    {
        set { sql_string = value; }
    }

    public string connection_string
    {

        set { strCon = value; }

    }

    public System.Data.DataSet GetConnection
    {

        get { return MyDataSet(); }

    }
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da_1;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
    System.Data.DataSet dat_set;


    public System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
    {
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon);
        con.Open();
        da_1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);
        dat_set = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");
        con.Close();
        return dat_set;
    }

    public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
    {

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);

        cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);



    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where exactly you are getting this error at what line?

Comment: Did you debug it? It should break exactly on the line that contains the null reference. And the null reference means you didn't initialize an object.

Comment: You never set the Update command for the data adapter. I think you need to call `cb.GetUpdateCommand()`, before you call `cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0])`

Comment: when i put in the form and then click submit button then getting this error

Comment: after adding cb.GetUpdateCommand() i am getting same error

Comment: At what line are you getting the error? Can you post the full stack trace this should tell you. Or better still (as suggested by Mark) debug the web page and it will tell you what is null.

Comment: I think when you are calling the method `UpdateDatabase` on instance of `Class1` that is `clas` is not to the instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

you can't have null value in some of the object . 
use the try and catch to find out the exact location and then try to initialize the object or provide some value which is causing the error.

try to handle this error yourself.